# Why is Unity Giving Me Build Errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, export

I cant seem to export my game. I have two errors but I dont know what they are as the console is not as clear.

The console error is.

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors 
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0020e] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:181 
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] 
in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:88 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

If someone can help me tell what error there is then I would be grateful.

Comment: I checked that one and it is about android and I am exporting my game to PC

Comment: Is that the whole error? Also, check your code for UnityEditor and UnityEditorInternal references in non-editor scripts.

Comment: Please show use the errors further up in the console ..  the ones you show here is just the very last result error that doesn't provide any information about **why** exactly the build failed only **that** it failed.

Comment: @Iggy unfortunately the linked question and answers are totally useless ^^ see my comment before: These two errors are only the final result **that** the build failed but don't provide any information **why** ...

Answer (score 0):

İ was having same issue and whole day i just researched the solution i tested almost everything...
i have finally solved it by following steps:
First i have uploaded my visiual studio editor to latest version.İ dont know it has any action on it but anyway.Then on Unity editor file >> build settings >> Player settings. Then there is below to Configuration section Scripting Backend mine was IL2CPP and i changed it to Mono.
İt works for me you can try it.